# Resize a div with fixed size ratio

Tags: jquery, css, html, resize

I made a div with width 100% and height width*.1 in jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/2drYk/

```
<figure class="container">
</figure>

$('.container').height($(this).width()*.1);

* 
{
margin:0; 
padding:0; 
border:0
}

.container
{
    width:100%;
    background:black;

}
```

How can I expand the height on click from here ?

Comment: have a look at `.click()` and `.animate()`

Comment: What have you tried? Also, what do you want it to resize to? Do you want to keep the fixed size ratio?

Comment: @Anzeo I tried css way but it's buggy. I would like it to be 400px height. I once it's clicked I dont want keep it, I just need the ratio when the div isn't resized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('.container').height($(this).width()*0.1);

$('.container').on('click',function(){
    $(this).animate({height: ($(this).width()*0.1 + $(this).height())});
});
```

demo here [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2drYk/2/)

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Is there a way to make it back to normal on second click ?

Comment: is there a way to set an exact height with this methode or it always depends on the base height ?

Comment: do you mean like this? `$(this).height(200)`

Comment: Yes, I tried earlier but when I do so it increases height in addition of ratio http://jsfiddle.net/2drYk/5/

Answer (score 1):

```
.container
{
    width:100%;
    background:black;
    transition:all 500ms;
    -webkit-transition:all 500ms;
    -o-transition:all 500ms;
}

.container.newheight{height:500px}

$('.container').on('click',function(){
   $(this).toggleClass('newheight');
});
```